# Usage of varargs in C

Tags: c, variadic-functions

[Here](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Example.html#Variadic-Example) is the example of `varargs`.

I'm a little puzzled.

#### [x]Question 1: How to get the n<sup>th</sup> argument?

```
va_list ap;
va_arg (ap + (n-1), int); // **INCORRECT USAGE**
```

Is it correct? If not, how to get the n<sup>th</sup> argument?

#### [x]Question 2: When will `ap` increase?

[It says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784729/an-example-of-use-of-varargs-in-c) `ap` will increase to the next argument, but if I use `va_arg(ap + (n-1), int), n>=2`, will `ap` increase?

#### Question 3: (BTW/maybe off-topic) What's ap abbreviated from?

Sometimes, we declared `Cnt` abbreviated from `Count` or `Counter`.

What's `ap` abbreviated from?

#### Question 4: Which type is `ap`?

I know it's `va_list` type, but what is `va_list`? struct? int? or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: `ap` is for additional parameters

Comment: `ap` might also be for *argument pointer*

Comment: 4: Do you mean `va_list`?

Comment: @self. Yes. That was a typo. sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the n-th argument you will have to call `va_arg()` with **correct type** n-1 times.

Your examples 1 and 2 are wrong. `ap` will be changed by `va_arg()` automatically.

Type of `va_list` is implementation defined, but is usually a `char*`.