# How can printf function can take variable parameters in number while output them?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I really wonder how printf executed. Is there a parameter array structure in C?  Can i define my custom function like printf?

Comment: Read about [`va_start`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start), [`va_arg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg) and [`va_end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_end). While that reference documentation is using the C++ `<cstdarg>`, change the header file to `<stdarg.h>` and you're good to go.

Comment: Check this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867229/code-for-printf-function-in-c

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function

Comment: You are talking about `varargs`. Another question deals with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784729/an-example-of-use-of-varargs-in-c

Comment: But then those 'articles' do not explain how it works, only how it's implemented.

Comment: Too bad. It was my understanding you were looking for an answer to "I really wonder how printf executed.", not "How can I _use_ it myself"

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++: Passing variable number of arguments around](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/c-c-passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A special type `va_list` is used for using variable list arguements. read [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html).

Comment: Thx. Really interesting but clean answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `va_arg` macro. Here's an example

```c
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdarg.h>     /* va_list, va_start, va_arg, va_end */

int FindMax (int n, ...)
{
  int i,val,largest;
  va_list vl;
  va_start(vl,n);
  largest=va_arg(vl,int);
  for (i=1;i<n;i++)
  {
    val=va_arg(vl,int);
    largest=(largest>val)?largest:val;
  }
  va_end(vl);
  return largest;
}

int main ()
{
  int m;
  m= FindMax (7,702,422,631,834,892,104,772);
  printf ("The largest value is: %d\n",m);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A program conforms to some specific [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) is defined by the abi.

A calling convention defines how parameters passed to a function, usually stored either in registers or/and on the stack.The function then retrieves the parameters accordingly and this is also for [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) functions.

Sure you can define variadic function yourself.