# C language format output printf function an output problem

Tags: c

## code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   int a=2;
   float b=9.99f;
   printf("1:%d\n",a,b);
   printf("2:%d、%f、%f\n",a);
   return 0;
}
```

## compilation option

The GCC compilation option is `GCC -m32 test.c -o test`

## The output

### $./test

1:2
2:2、9.990000

## doubt

In the second printf statement, there is only one expression, a, but it prints the values of two variables

## stack data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMpET.png)

Comment: In this case "wrong" includes not providing the required variables.

Comment: Why providing more than required number of variables to the format specifier of the printf function ?

Comment: For variadic functions, providing excess arguments is fine but not providing enough is bound to cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Change compilation arguments to: `GCC -Werror -Wall -m32 test.c -o test`. Read the warnings, try to understand what they are telling you, and then fix your code accordingly.

Comment: I think this answer correctly clears your doubt https://stackoverflow.com/a/23104629/8504592

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect format specifiers which results in compiler warnings. In the second `printf` statement format ‘%f’ expects a matching ‘double’ argument Here is the correct version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   int a=2;
   float b=9.99f;
   printf("1:%d %f\n",a,b);
   printf("2:%d\n",a);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know the correct way to do it, but this is a problem finding process, I don't know how to implement printf, use GDB to debug, you can see 9.99 is also on the stack, %f is not pushed but still output