# In which register does the scanf function store input values?

Tags: c, assembly, stack, scanf, disassembly

I have the following disassembly of a main function in which a user input is stored using scanf function (at address `0x0000089c`). Due to the comparison that is made, I suppose that the user input is stored into the rsp register but I cannot figure out why, as rsp doesn't seem to be pushed on the stack (at least, not near the call to the scanf function).
Here is the disassembly:

```
0x00000850 sub rsp, 0x18
0x00000854 mov rax, qword fs:[0x28]
0x0000085d mov qword [canary], rax
0x00000862 xor eax, eax
0x00000864 call fcn.00000a3c
0x00000869 lea rsi, str.Insert_input:
0x00000870 mov edi, 1
0x00000875 xor eax, eax
0x00000877 mov dword [rsp], 0
0x0000087e mov dword [var_4h], 0
0x00000886 call sym.imp.__printf_chk
0x0000088b lea rdx, [var_4h]
0x00000890 lea rdi, str.u__u  ; "%u %u" ;const char *format
0x00000897 xor eax, eax
0x00000899 mov rsi, rsp
0x0000089c call sym.imp.__isoc99_scanf ; int scanf(const char *format)
0x000008a1 mov eax, dword [rsp]
0x000008a4 cmp eax, 0x1336
0x000008a9 jg 0x867
```

Comment: The parameters of `scanf` (except the format string that is) are not passed in registers, but rather on the stack. Though, technically, the way that parameters are passed to variadic functions is platform-dependent, but you can read more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104628/technically-how-do-variadic-functions-work-how-does-printf-work

Comment: @Ætérnal this is wrong, on x64, the first 6 arguments are passed in following registers in that order: rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9. Only if there are 7 or more arguments, arguments 7 to N are pushed on the stack. Also I don't know what makes you think the format string pointer is passed on the stack her, it is passed in rdi.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Let's suppose that the architecture is x86 so the parameters are passed on the stack.  Moreover, rsp is used as the stack frame pointer and so it contains a poniter to the topmost element on the stack. So why does, in this case, rsp contain the user input as it isn't the topmost element on the stack?

Comment: @Giovanna the architecture in your sample is x64, there are no `rxx` registers (like rdx, rdi, rsp etc.) on x86.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes, you're right. So why does rsp, and not rdi, contain the user input?

Comment: @Giovanna it doesn't. `rsp` _points_ to the variable that will contain the user input.

Comment: @Jabberwocky is this a general rule when using scanf?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `scanf`. Here for whatever reason `rsp`  points to some (probably local) variable where the user input should go, IOW that variable is on the stack. After `mov rsi, rsp`, `rsi`points to that variable, and as explained before `rsi` is the second argument for `scanf` and the second argument of `scanf` is the address where the user input shopuld be stored. You need to study all this calling convention stuff and assembly stuff, I'm sure it's explained in your learning material.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I think that I have understood what you're saying. I thought that scanf had just an argument (the user input) and that that parameter should have been saved in rdi, that's why I didn't figure out why rsp is pointing to the variable with the user input... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On x86_64, parameters are passed in registers, so your call to scanf has 3 parameters stored in 3 registers:

- `rdi` pointer to the string `"%u %u"`, the format to parse (two unsigned integers)
- `rsi` should be a `unsigned *`, pointer to where to put the first parsed integer
- `rdx` pointer to where to put the second parsed integer.

If you look just before the call, `rsi` is set to `rsp` (the stack pointer) while `rdx` is set to point at the global variable `var_4h` (an extern symbol not defined here).

The stack is used to hold local variables, and in this case `rsp` points at a block 0x18 "free" bytes (allocated in the first instruction in your block), which is enough space for 6 integers.  The one at offset 0 from `rsp` is what `rsi` points to, and it is the value read by the mov instruction immediately after the call.

Comment: Thanks, you've been very clear! So, is it correct to say that rsp (at offset 0) and rsi point to the same block after the scanf call?

Comment: Actually, only before the call -- scanf might modify esi internally (it is not caller save).

Comment: So, before the scanf call, rsp (at offset 0) and rsi point both to the bock which will contain the user input, did I understand?

Comment: rsp and rsi both point at the block, which is at offset 0 from either of them

Comment: After the call to scanf, the integer at offset 0 from rsp will contain the user input, right?

Comment: The variable meant to capture the output of the `%u` is on the stack, that is the only relation with `rsp`.  Otherwise `rsp` is communicating to `scanf` where the stack is in case it wants some stack space to use for itself.  Here, with 3 parameters, `rsp` is not involved in any parameter passing for this call, except sharing where the current stack  pointer is, and hence identifying where free stack memory is.