# Variadic Functions in C Concept

Tags: c, macros, variadic-functions

I'm not very clear on the concept of variadic functions in C.
In practice, what do macros like va_list, va_start, va_end represent?

From what I understand va_start declares a list, va_start inizialize it and va_end it's a cleanup. But I don't understand how to use them in practice and it's not clear to me what the macros represent when I look at them at a lower level of abstraction.

A more practical explanation of this concept with some examples if possible would be very useful to me, thanks.

Comment: Basically the only use is for mimicking the skunky old printf/scanf functions. Variadic functions has been recognized as major design mistake in C which should never have been allowed. Va lists are notoriously unsafe and also cumbersome to work with. The only reason you need to ponder these things is if you are struggling with maintaining some old, rotten code base. Never use `stdarg.h` in new projects. (I'm sure authors of rotten code will disagree in comments soon.)

Comment: The main thing is the `va_list` *thing* (almost like a pointer). `va_start()` sets it up, `va_arg()` uses and updates it, `va_end()` cleans up. The `va_list` *thing* works like a pointer to the next item in the `...` arguments.

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) Unfortunately this isn't a "forum" or tutorial site, but better suited for rather narrow and specific questions.

Comment: If you want to know the common cases where variadic functions are used, I can say that in most cases they are used for printf like functions where variable number of parameters are used for to generate a formatted string. They are useful for custom logger and error handling functions. They can be also used to define a single function to perform multiple operations depending on the number of parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Technically, how do variadic functions work? How does printf work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104628/technically-how-do-variadic-functions-work-how-does-printf-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the early days of C language, the passing parameters contract was that parameters were put into the stack in reverse order. And neither the type nor the number of parameters were part of the function declaration, only its return value type. It was then easy to handle a variable number of parameters (at least in assembly code) provided that number could be deduced from the fix part. As already said in comments, it is exactly the way the `printf` and `scanf` functions from the standard library work.

The `va_*` things from `stdarg.h` were later added as a *portable* way to handle those variadic functions directly in C language, and they were designated as *opaque macros*. The rationale was that the the gory details of passing parameters were details for the language implementations, and the implementation only had to provide a way for the C programmer to be able to access the parameters *the hard way* meaning here knowing their order and type at run time instead of at compile time.

In common implementations, they are just a way to extract a pointer in the program stack to the *frame* containing the parameters and to iterate that frame.

For an example of usage, you could have a look the the excellent [cppreference site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic)