# addObject and initWithObjects difference for arrays in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

```
NSMutableArray *firstColumn = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[firstColumn addObject:tile1];
[firstColumn addObject:tile2];
[firstColumn addObject:tile3];
```

When you use **addObject** on to a NSMUtableArray, we do not add *"nil"* but when **initWithObjects** is used, there is a *"nil"* parameter in the statement.

What does nil signify? Does it mention that it's reaching the end of the Array ?

```
 NSMutableArray *thirdCoulmn =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:tile7,tile8,tile9,nil];
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a sentinel value.  varargs functions either need a sentinal value or some other way to keep track (eg printf uses the format string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, this doesn't have to do with `NSMutableArray`, but the `vargs` features (variable arguments). It uses a sentinel value, `nil`, to determine the end of the argument list.

Search for [vargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784729/an-example-of-use-of-varargs-in-c) to learn more about this feature.