# Pass along arguments of varargs functions

Tags: c

Say I want to implement a function

```
void myprintf(const char* format, ...){
   printf("Hello world!\n"),
   printf(format, ...);
}
```

I.e. I want to pass along the varargs list to printf. Is there any convenient way to do this?

Comment: @embedded_crysis Please, google "c varargs". These answers I have found (among tons of others): [SO: An example of use of varargs in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784729/an-example-of-use-of-varargs-in-c), [SO: Passing variable number of arguments around](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. However the library functions in the `printf` family offer a [`vprintf` varaint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) that accepts a `va_list` as an argument instead of ellipsis. And it is in fact a good practice to offer such a variant if you happen to be writing your own variable argument function.

Your wrapper would then be something like this:

```
void myprintf(const char* format, ...){
   printf("Hello world!\n"),
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, format);
   vprintf(format, args);
   va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With a little help of the preprocessor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define myprintf(...) \
do { \
   printf("Hello world!\n"), \
   printf(__VA_ARGS__); \
} while (0)

int main(void)
{    
    myprintf("%s %d\n", "Hello", 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You got my vote, but I still really don't like where this line of thinking can lead to...

Comment: Thank you @StoryTeller, I agree and also prefer _va_list_

Comment: This is cool, but I don't really understand it :) while(0)?

Comment: @embedded_crysis, it is a multistatement operation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/257418/1606345